# How to achieve https://www.gogoro.com/smartscooter/smarter/ iphone like screenshots

Tags: jquery, iphone, html

Anybody knows if there is a plugin for doing the iphone screenshots effects like the one in the page

https://www.gogoro.com/smartscooter/smarter/

I've been searching around but couldn't find it..

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is called **parallax scrolling**.

Here are two very nice plugin you can use:

1. scrollMagic
2. skrollr

Here is examples from awwwards website.

[30 Great Websites with Parallax Scrolling](http://www.awwwards.com/30-great-websites-with-parallax-scrolling.html)